# Is it posible to add properties to an object in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following function

```
public static void UpdateWithStoredProcedure<T>(string storedProcedure, T entity)
{
    var command = PrepareCommand(CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
    AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand(command, entity);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I call it this way

```
UpdateWithStoredProcedure(DeleteDocumentStyleProcedure, new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Id", DocumentStyle.DocumentId));
```

Is there a way to pass two parameters. I mean, two KeyValuePair instances? I tried passing a list and dictionary, but the code for AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand also maps the internal properties of this classes like Count.

Comment: What's `AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand`?

Comment: It sounds like you really need to change the "AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand" method.  Without being able to see it, what about passing it an array?

Comment: I can't change AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand. What it does, it's that it iterates through all the object properties and gets its values. I believe using reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I declared a new internal class with just the properties I needed and passed an instance of it to the  `AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand` function.

```
class UpdateLogoParameters
{
    public byte[] Logo{get;set;}
    public int DocumentId{get;set;}

    public UpdateLogoParameters(byte[] logo, int documentId)
    {
       Logo = logo;
       DocumentId = documentId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the function to iterate through the entities:

```
public static void UpdateWithStoredProcedure<T>(string storedProcedure, params T[] entities)
    {
        var command = PrepareCommand(CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
        foreach(T entity in entities)
            AddObjectPropertiesAsParametersToCommand(command, entity);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```